# Casting Double to Long is giving wrong value

Tags: c++, casting

I have the following code:

```
double num = 1234567891234567899.111;
long num2 = (long) num;
std::cout << num1 << std::endl;
```

O/P: `1234567891234567936 //Expected 1234567891234567899`
**( last three digits before floating point )**

[The Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccdh6.png)

Comment: A double has 15 to 17 digits of precision. The last 3 numbers are not stored in the double so don't expect them to be preserved. Related: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: See this: [https://ideone.com/sqEwO8](https://ideone.com/sqEwO8) to see that the loss of precision is with the `double` and not the cast.